# What is the default user and password for elasticsearch?

Tags: docker, authentication, elasticsearch, credentials

I have [installed Elastic with Docker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html):

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 \
           -p 9300:9300 \
           -e "discovery.type=single-node" \ 
           docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.2
```

But `curl localhost:9200` fails with an authentication error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "security_exception",
        "reason": "missing authentication token for REST request [/]",
        "header": {
          "WWW-Authenticate": "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""
        }
      }
    ],
    "type": "security_exception",
    "reason": "missing authentication token for REST request [/]",
    "header": {
      "WWW-Authenticate": "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""
    }
  },
  "status": 401
}
```

**What is the default username/password combo for Elasticsearch?**

Answer (score 97):

[Defaults are](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/security-getting-started.html):

```
user: elastic
password: changeme
```

So:

```
$ curl -u elastic:changeme localhost:9200
{
  "name" : "5aEHJ-Y",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "3FmaYN7rS56oBTqWOyxmKA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.6.2",
    "build_hash" : "57e20f3",
    "build_date" : "2017-09-23T13:16:45.703Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Read more about [changing the defaults](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/security-getting-started.html).

Comment: not working.
`[2018-06-01T13:59:42,602][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.AuthenticationService] [KBgeNNv] Authentication of [elastic] was terminated by realm [reserved] - failed to authenticate user [elastic]`

Answer (score 26):

### Setting up username and password for Elastic Search: (ES version:7.5.2) (Ubuntu 18.04)

Step 1: First enable xpackmonitoring in elasticsearch.yml file

```
root@flax:/etc/elasticsearch# vim elasticsearch.yml

Add the following line to the end of file:
    xpack.security.enabled: true

File Contents:
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
network.host: 127.0.0.1
http.host: 0.0.0.0
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
xpack.security.enabled: true
```

Step 2:
    Go to /usr/share/elasticsearch folder:

```
root@flax:/usr/share/elasticsearch# systemctl start elasticsearch

root@flax:/usr/share/elasticsearch# ./bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive

Initiating the setup of passwords for reserved users elastic,apm_system,kibana,logstash_system,beats_system,remote_monitoring_user.
You will be prompted to enter passwords as the process progresses.
Please confirm that you would like to continue [y/N]y


Enter password for [elastic]: 
Reenter password for [elastic]: 
Enter password for [apm_system]: 
Reenter password for [apm_system]: 
Enter password for [kibana]: 
Reenter password for [kibana]: 
Enter password for [logstash_system]: 
Reenter password for [logstash_system]: 
Enter password for [beats_system]: 
Reenter password for [beats_system]: 
Passwords do not match.
Try again.
Enter password for [beats_system]: 
Reenter password for [beats_system]: 
Enter password for [remote_monitoring_user]: 
Reenter password for [remote_monitoring_user]: 
Changed password for user [apm_system]
Changed password for user [kibana]
Changed password for user [logstash_system]
Changed password for user [beats_system]
Changed password for user [remote_monitoring_user]
Changed password for user [elastic]

root@flax:/usr/share/elasticsearch# systemctl restart elasticsearch

root@flax:/usr/share/elasticsearch# systemctl restart elasticsearch.service
```

Comment: ```./bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords: No such file or directory```

Comment: @OliverDixon You need to install the "default" version of ES, not the OSS version in package managers.

Comment: ensure you are in ```/usr/share/elasticsearch``` directory

Answer (score 16):

Please be careful about the version of ElasticSearch.
In **7.2** parameter ELASTIC_PASSWORD works.

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 \
           -p 9300:9300 \
           -e "discovery.type=single-node" \ 
           -e "ELASTIC_PASSWORD=my_own_password" \
```

But also this line should be added in elasticsearch.yml:

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
```

By default, it is not there.

[Security settings list](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-settings.html#general-security-settings)

Comment: only thing that would make the answer more complete is some kind of link to a list of other options like this

Answer (score 12):

If you enabled basic x-pack security using `xpack.security.enabled: true` in your elasticsearch version 7.7(at the time of writing this answer), it will not have a default password(`changeme`) as it used to be in the old version of x-pack.

As mentioned in the [getting started with security official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/6.2/security-getting-started.html)

> X-Pack security provides a built-in elastic superuser you can use to
> start setting things up. This elastic user has full access to the
> cluster, including all indices and data, **so the elastic user does
> not have a password set by default.**

So you need to change the password of `elastic`, if you want to do it after the installation then follow [setting password for built-in users in interactive mode guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-users.html#set-built-in-user-passwords)

which requires you to run below command from elasticsearch bin folder.

```
bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive
```

Answer (score 7):

**To Set up username and password**

ssh to the system, stop elasticsearch and kibana service, then run the following command

```
sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

update this file, enable security by adding the following line

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
```

**Change the password**

Execute the following step to change the password

step 1:

```
 cd /usr/share/elasticsearch/
```

step 2:

```
sudo bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto
```

> auto - Uses randomly generated passwords interactive - Uses passwords
> entered by a user

or

```
sudo bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive
```

> you can run the command in an "interactive" mode, which prompts you to
> enter new passwords for the elastic, kibana_system, logstash_system,
> beats_system, apm_system, and remote_monitoring_user users:

The above commands can help you to setup a password

**Start Elasticsearch**

1. Start the Elasticsearch service by running a systemctl command:

   sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service

It may take some time for the system to start the service. There will be no output if successful.

2. Enable Elasticsearch to start on boot:

   sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch.service

**Start and Enable Kibana**

1. Start the Kibana service:

   sudo systemctl start kibana

There is no output if the service starts successfully.

2. Next, configure Kibana to launch at boot:

   sudo systemctl enable kibana

Comment: Where is the process to add or change username?

Answer (score 5):

Adding below two lines in `\elasticsearch-8.2.2\config\elasticsearch.yml`

```
# Enable security features
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true
```

and restart the server works for me, it prints password onto console with -u as username
[image]

Comment: How do you restart the server when it is inside the supported Docker container? It does not seem to be run by systemctl, for example.

Comment: So, @dixon1e this is I ran over CMD the .bat file, no docker container in this case, But It would be great if such option available, I will need to dig into more about this docker case. but here its a simple app executing on Windows OS.

Answer (score 2):

In Elasticsearch version 6.x - you can specify initial password for *elastic* user using *ELASTIC_PASSWORD* env variable.

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 \
           -p 9300:9300 \
           -e "discovery.type=single-node" \ 
           -e "ELASTIC_PASSWORD=my_own_password" \
           docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.4
```

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/configuring-tls-docker.html

Comment: this will only work if you buy a paid licence as this feature needs the commercial "x-pack security" addon

Comment: Since ELK Stack 6.8 and 7.X xpack became default feature of basic license.

Answer (score 2):

For ES 8.4.3 we can reset elastic search password like below

```
sudo docker exec -it es01 /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I run the version of 8.8.0 I used , when you try running for the first time,
it shows the password and username in logs, when you run it , search for the data like below in cmd it is almost latest line (I run it in windows):

```
 Password for the elastic user (reset with `bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic`):
```

if you don't seen in the first time, just remove the elastic folder and extract again, I do this. it is simplest way for .

Answer (score 1):

in the CommandPrompt go to elastic folder :

```
C:\Users\username>cd C:\your_elastic_folder\bin
```

execute

```
elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive
```

and set up your passwords. After that you can log in your http://localhost:9200/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the latest version of elasticsearch. When I installed elasticsearch 7.14.0 it worked! If your interested,I have a youtube video on it : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqgYebLacYI.

Answer (score 0):

For version 8.4.3, you need to do these steps:

1. Update config\elasticsearch.yml to add `xpack.security.enabled: true`
2. Run this to create a keystore if got this kind of error message:

   "ERROR: Elasticsearch keystore file is missing"

   Run `bin/elasticsearch-keystore create -p`
3. Start Elastic search: `bin/elasticsearch`
4. Update password `bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive`

```
Note: The 'elasticsearch-setup-passwords' tool has been deprecated. This command will be removed in a future release.
******************************************************************************

Initiating the setup of passwords for reserved users elastic,apm_system,kibana,kibana_system,logstash_system,beats_system,remote_monitoring_user.
You will be prompted to enter passwords as the process progresses.
Please confirm that you would like to continue [y/N]
```

Answer (score 0):

To reset and get an updated password for user elastic with minimal output and no prompts, try

bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic -abs

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/reset-password.html