# ElasticSearch on local machine Windows 10 asking Username & Password

Tags: elasticsearch

I am just started exploring about the Elasticsearch + Kibana + Logstash combined as my requirement of integration this with other tool chains.

I have tried to successfully downloading of ElasticSearch & Kibana from official websites.
https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana
https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch

And I am able to start the ElasticSearch as well.
[image]

When I go to browser to access this it is asking for me to enter credentials.
I saw lots of tutorials on youtube no one faced this problem.
[image]
Need to know what settings of configuration needs to apply here ?

My OS is : `Windows-10`

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46627979/what-is-the-default-user-and-password-for-elasticsearch ... `elastic:changeme`

Comment: thanx @DiegoDeVita for taking your time for this might be repeated question, I tried 1 trick and works for me, have posted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding below two lines in `\elasticsearch-8.2.2\config\elasticsearch.yml`

```
# Enable security features
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true
```

[image]